# Can I store anything I want in com.google.android.gms.cast.MediaMetadata?

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

The documentation from google is giving a 404 error right now so I can't read it.

It appears that I can put any strings I want into the MediaMetadata but when I go to retrieve them from the VCM (VideoCastManager) they aren't there. Is there any way to add custom data to the MediaMetadata?

I want this so I can have more information about the video I am playing when the application reconnects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue....and I found the cause to be how I was constructing my MediaMetaData object in my sender app's code.

Constructing the MediaMetadata object in your receiver app's code with the constant MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE (as is done in the CastCompanionLibrary sample) won't let you store anything with .putString(key,value) other than with the keys MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE and MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE.

Here's what I've found....

Since I'm playing video on the chromecast, I assumed the best way to construct the MediaMetadata object was to use the MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE constant like so :

```
MediaMetadata castMetaData = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
```

Then....I attempted to send the following data with the MediaMetadata object:

```
castMetaData.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE,"videoTitle");
castMetaData.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_SUBTITLE,"videoSubTitle");
castMetaData.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST,"videoArtistName");
```

After sending this MediaMetadata object to the receiver (ensuring that the three KEYs and their corresponding values were in-tact) and video began to play, I attempted a call to retrieve the video's metadata from the receiver with :

```
MediaMetadata receiverMetadata = videoCastManager.getRemoteMediaInformation().getMetaData();
```

This returned a MediaMetadata object, but the MediaMetadata.KEY_ARTIST mapping was no where to be found.

After changing the MediaMetadata construct parameter to MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_GENERIC like so I was able to send more metadata in the MediaMetadata object:

```
MediaMetadata castMetaData = new MediaMetadata(MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_GENERIC);
```

**Note**
I don't know if constructing the MediaMetadata object with MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_GENERIC is OK when the actual task is to play video.

Comment: Just to confirm that `MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_GENERIC` allows for custom fields.
I've tried `MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_USER` (user-defined) and custom fields didn't hold any value.

Answer (score 0):

What is VCM?  You can add any pair of key/values to the MediaMetadat, use one of the variations of `put*()` such as `putInt(key,value)`, `putString(key, value)`, etc. Then retrieve them by corresponding `get*()` methods. On your receiver side, you'll have a JSON with those key/value pairs so you can easily retrieve them there too.

Comment: Sorry I shouldn't have abbreviated, the VideoCastManager. So basically I want to put any data I want in there and then I want to be able to retrieve when I reconnect from the sender end, not the receiver end.

Comment: following what I mentioned, aren't you getting those?

Comment: I'll have to test again but basically I can call `putString("test","test")`, then play a movie file, close my app, reopen it, reconnect, call `videoCastManager.getRemoteMediaInformation()` and get the metadata, then do a `getString` and it is null. On the debugger I see the metadata only has the "com.google.android.gms.cast.metadata.TITLE", which is the only other value I'm setting.

Comment: Do you see that "test" attribute in your receiver log when you send it (in the first session)?

Comment: I am using the default media player, not a custom receiver, how do I go about looking something like this up?

Comment: Open a chrome debugger to your chromecast (http://<chromecast-ip>:9222). Then launch your app from your android device, then on the browser, refresh the page, click on the link and open the console in the debugger. If you don't see many messages, then you need to add logging by typing the following in the console: cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG); then you should see more logs and when you cast a movie, you can see the json messages. See if your custom attribute shows up there

Comment: Yeap it shows up in there inside the json object. I just can't retrieve it on the sender end. Here is a snippet of what it shows `\"metadata\":{\"test\":\"test1\",\"title\":`

Comment: So just to be clear, I should be seeing the values come back to the Sender application when a call to `getRemoteMediaInformation` is made and this is a bug? or should I just start looking into creating my own custom receiver?

Comment: The recommended approach is to use the CustomData. I haven't tested whether the additional fields find their way back to the sender or not, so I can't be sure it is happening; I personally expected/hoped it would but I need to test that and look at the source code to see if it is handled or not.

Comment: Does CustomData work with the default media player or only with a custom receiver?